# XY is not a function - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Ok, I get this error in my console:
    - $(".homecolumn").sortable is not a function

I have no idea why, the idea is that when I click text aka  it triggers that code, nothing happens. I've got this error quite few times, I would really low to see long-term solution on this issue.

Here is my full jquery code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#intellisearchval").keyup(function () {
        var intellisearchlength = $("#intellisearchval").val().length;
        if (intellisearchlength>2) {
        $.post("search.php", { intellisearch: "true", value: $("#intellisearchval").val() },
          function(data){
            $("#searchresults").html(data);
            $("#searchresults").slideDown("slow");
          });
        }
    });
    $("#intellisearchcancel").click(function () {
        $("#intellisearchval").val("");
        $("#searchresults").slideUp("slow");
    });
    $(".datepick").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/showcalendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
    $(".homecolumn").sortable({
    handle : '.widget-header',
    connectWith: ['.homecolumn'],
    stop: function() { saveHomeWidgets(); }
});
$( ".homewidget" ).find( ".widget-header" ).prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>");
resHomeWidgets();
$( ".widget-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
    $( this ).parents( ".homewidget:first" ).find( ".widget-content" ).toggle();
    saveHomeWidgets();
});
$.post("index.php", { getwhmcsnews: 1 },
    function(data){
        jQuery("#whmcsnewsfeed").html(data);
    });
jQuery.post("index.php", { getincomeforecast: 1 },
    function(data){
      jQuery("#incomeforecast").html(data);
    });
loadTickets();
jQuery.post("index.php", { getsystemoverview: 1 },
    function(data){
        jQuery("#systemoverviewstats").html(data);
});
jQuery.post("index.php", { getincome: 1 },
    function(data){
        jQuery("#incometotals").html(data);
    });$("#geninvoices").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {'Yes': function() {
            window.location='index.php?generateinvoices=true'
        },'No': function() {
            window.location='index.php?generateinvoices=true&noemails=true'
        }}
});

  });
  var savedOrders = new Array();
savedOrders[1] = "system_overview:true,client_activity:true,admin_activity:true,activity_log:true,income_forecast:true";
savedOrders[2] = "orders_overview:true,network_status:true,todo_list:true,my_notes:true,open_invoices:true,sysinfo:true,whmcs_news:true,income_overview:true";
function saveHomeWidgets() {
    var orderdata = '';
    $(".homecolumn").each(function(index, value){
        var colid = value.id;
        var order = $("#"+colid).sortable("toArray");
        for ( var i = 0, n = order.length; i < n; i++ ) {
            var v = $('#' + order[i] ).find('.widget-content').is(':visible');
            order[i] = order[i] + ":" + v;
        }
        orderdata = orderdata + order + "|";
    });
    $.post("index.php", { saveorder: "1", widgetdata: orderdata });
}
function resHomeWidgets() {
    var IDs = '';
    var IDsp = '';
    var widgetID = '';
    var visible = '';
    var widget = '';
    for (var z = 1, y = 2; z <= y; z++ ) {
        if (savedOrders[z]) {
            IDs = savedOrders[z].split(',');
            for (var i = 0, n = IDs.length; i < n; i++ ) {
                IDsp = (IDs[i].split(':'));
                widgetID = IDsp[0];
                visible = IDsp[1];
                widget = $(".homecolumn").find('#' + widgetID).appendTo($('#homecol'+z));
                if (visible === 'false') {
                    widget.find(".ui-icon").toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
                    widget.find(".widget-content").hide();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function showDialog(name) {
$("#"+name).dialog('open');
}
{/literal}
{$jquerycode}
{$jscode}
</script>
<script>
</script>
</head>



<body>

<div id="topnav">
    <div id="welcome">Welcome Back <strong>{$admin_username}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;- <a href="../" title="Client Area">Client Area</a> | <a href="myaccount.php" title="My Account">My Account</a> | <a href="logout.php" title="Logout">Logout</a></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="logo_container" >
    <div id='the_logo_image'></div>
 <div id="intellisearch">
    <!--<strong>Intelligent Search</strong><br />-->

    <div style="padding-top: 47px;margin-left:105px;" >

        <input type="text" id="intellisearchval" style='width:260px; line-height:20px;font-size:17px;background-color:transparent;border:none;'/>
        <img src="images/delete.png" alt="Cancel" id="intellisearchcancel" class="absmiddle" style='margin-top: -8px; margin-left: -3px; cursor:pointer;' />
    </div>

    <div align="left" id="searchresults"></div>

  </div>
</div>



<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu1, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();" onclick="window.location='index.php'"><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu2, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();" onclick="window.location='clients.php'"><a href="clients.php" title="Clients">Clients</a></li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu3, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();" onclick="window.location='orderitems.php'"><a href="orderitems.php" title="Orders">Orders</a></li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu4, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();" onclick="window.location='transactions.php'"><a href="transactions.php" title="Billing">Billing</a></li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu5, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();" onclick="window.location='supportcenter.php'"><a href="supportcenter.php" title="Support">Support</a></li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu6, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();" onclick="window.location='reports.php'"><a href="reports.php" title="Reports">Reports</a></li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu7, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();">Utilities</li>
    <li class="navbutton" onmouseover="this.className='navbuttonover';dropdownmenu(this, event, menu8, '');" onmouseout="this.className='navbutton';delayhidemenu();">Setup</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="date_div"><div id="date_div2"></div></div>
</div>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
// Simulates PHP's date function
Date.prototype.format = function(format) {
    var returnStr = '';
    var replace = Date.replaceChars;
    for (var i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {
        var curChar = format.charAt(i);
        if (replace[curChar]) {
            returnStr += replace[curChar].call(this);
        } else {
            returnStr += curChar;
        }
    }
    return returnStr;
};
Date.replaceChars = {
    shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    longMonths: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    shortDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    longDays: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],

    // Day
    D: function() { return Date.replaceChars.shortDays[this.getDay()]; },
    l: function() { return Date.replaceChars.longDays[this.getDay()]; },
    j: function() { return this.getDate(); },
    // Month
    F: function() { return Date.replaceChars.longMonths[this.getMonth()]; },
    M: function() { return Date.replaceChars.shortMonths[this.getMonth()]; },
    // Year
    Y: function() { return this.getFullYear(); },
    // Time
    a: function() { return this.getHours() < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm'; },
    A: function() { return this.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'; },
    g: function() { return this.getHours() % 12 || 12; },
    G: function() { return this.getHours(); },
    h: function() { return ((this.getHours() % 12 || 12) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (this.getHours() % 12 || 12); },
    H: function() { return (this.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + this.getHours(); },
    i: function() { return (this.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + this.getMinutes(); },
    s: function() { return (this.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + this.getSeconds(); },
    // Timezone
};

function startTime()
{
var d=new Date();
var s = d.format("l F j, Y g:i:s A");
document.getElementById('date_div2').innerHTML='<small>' + s + '</small>';
t=setTimeout('startTime()',1000);
}

window.onload
{
    startTime();
}
</script>
```

and HTML:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th style="font-weight: normal;">Verifications</th>
    <th style="font-weight: normal;" width="50">&nbsp;</th>
    <th style="font-weight: normal;" width="100">International</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you loaded the table sortable plugin? And that the plugin loaded AFTER jQuery loaded?

Comment: Check that your table is well-formed; i.e. your thead has one row with the same amount of th as your tbody rows have tds.

Comment: Reducing the code to only what is necessary would make your post more readable/useful, and in the process you'd probably solve your own problem. `sortable()` requires jquery UI (it's not in the standard jquery library), are you loading it?

Comment: I think you din't load the required library. You need to load Jquery UI along with jquery

Comment: Jquery UI is loaded. Everything looks as it should :S

Answer (score 0):

### Source

It's hard to determine the source of your issue, mostly because it's messy and lacks structure.
As people have commented already, the most likely issue is that you're loading the libraries in the wrong order or not at all.

I **seriously** recommend you separate your html code and your javascript code, [it has been shown to be quicker in most cases](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external), and it is also alot cleaner.
Inline javascript code is messy and I always try to steer clear from it. Instead, create a javascript file and link it in after all the other libraries.

```html
<script src="library1.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="library2.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

### Example

Anyway, here's a clean example of how it should be done

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <!-- JQuery core -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- JQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sortable").sortable();
            $("#sortable").disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the documentation for [`.sortable()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) in case you're lost.

---

### JSFiddle

And [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFY4U/) doing the same thing as above.

---

### Debugging guide

I've also found [this debugging guide](http://www.javascriptsource.com/debug-guide.html) you might be interested in; could come in handy if you get into more trouble.